# Returning EF entities using WCF - Read only web service / public API

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

I'm currently migrating an application from Linq-to-SQL & ASP.net Web Services (asmx) to Entity Framework and WCF.

My question is, I have a bunch of POCO classes which i have xml mapping files for (for the linq to sql)
I've replaced my linq to sql with an entity framework data model

I've got an interface - something like IService - that has all the methods on it that i need my service to implement - for example:

```
Product[] GetProductsByKeyword(string keyword);
```

In the above case, **Product** is a POCO.
I now have them as entities within my ef data model - i'm using .net 4, and could take advantage of poco support, but don't really see the need -
This service is strictly read only.

What's the best way of returning entities in my WCF service?
I want it to support other client platforms, not just .net (so php guys could use it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [OData](http://www.odata.org/). It's *extremely* simple when you already have an entity model. Here's [an example with a schema which may look familiar](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx).

Then [you can use PHP just as easily](http://odataphp.codeplex.com/). And [lots of other languages and frameworks](http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk), too.